# How to use Node from command line in VS Code with Nodist? (Windows 10)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, nodist

I have Nodist installed on my Windows 10 computer, but VS Code is not letting me use node commands in the Terminal. Please help, nothing works and I need an answer.

Comment: check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-windows and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/beginners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have node installed.

- Shift + Command + P to open the command pallete.
- Select "Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal"
- type node -v

This this command doesn't work and there is an error, then you need to install node.js (https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Visual Studio Code is just a text editor. It can only edit documents. It can't run code.

Answer (score 0):

Although I got this from Nodist's Github site, but I really don't know where to set this. There is no good document. I give up at last and use nvm or n.
————————————————
Make it work in your IDE
If your IDE cannot access node or npm right away, don’t fret! Find the relevant configuration settings and either set path\to\Nodist\bin as the Node installation dir or set path\to\Nodist\bin\node.exe as the path to the node binary directly.

Similar for npm: either set ...\Nodist\bin as the installation path or ...\Nodist\bin\npm.cmd directly. Some IDEs (eg. WebStorm) require you to set the path to an npm package containing bin\npm-cli.js. Nodist comes with a proxy npm folder: Simply set ...\Nodist\npm as the npm package (this feature is experimental and feedback is appreciated!).
————————————————
https://github.com/nullivex/nodist#make-it-work-in-your-ide